# Working round the lack of formula fields of type "Lookup Relationship"

Tags: formula, lookup, master-detail

When you have a master-detail chain of objects several levels deep, sometimes a lookup field to the root object on each child object is helpful for easy navigation or to show deeper records than the immediate child records as a root object related list.

It is a while since I set something like this up, and in the past have had to do it via triggers because it is not possible to create a formula field of type "Lookup Relationship".

Has anything changed in the platform to make solving this problem easier e.g. declarative rather than code?

Comment: personally, i'd do this in a domain class for each child object as it avoids any recursion from a PB (plus you'll end up with testmethods). But PB should work

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Do you mean that the domain class writes the lookup or that you use the domain class to navigate up and down the relationships? I want to be able to show e.g. the grand-child objects as a related list using layout UI, so need fields too.

Comment: Domain class writes the lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but this should be possible with Process Builder/Flow (on the child objects). Those do especially support cross-object formulas while workflow field updates don't.

Reparenting on an intermediate level may still require some sophistication (e.g. in a hierarchy Level_0__c <-- Level_1__c <-- Level_2__c, if you have a lookup from Level_2__c to Level_0__c and allow reparenting of a Level_1__c record to a different Level_0__c record - how do you update the lookups from all Level_2__c children of that Level_1__c record to the new Level_0__c record).